# Is it possible to POST files/images to jupyter kernel gateway API?

Tags: python, api, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I was trying out the `jupyter kernel gateway` and I can easily do `GET` and `POST` requests with little amounts of data.
I tried sending images using `POST` and it **failed**.
I was wondering if it was possible, and if possible can someone please help me out here?

I wanted to add the tag `jupyter-kernel-gateway` but it hasn't yet been created.

Comment: can you show what you have tried? maybe there's an issue with your code

Comment: I wrote a simple Flask code to test it out. Should I post all the codes here? I think I should, maybe it'd help. Can't do harm to post I guess. But the Flask thing works perfectly. I simply don't understand how I can make it work with the jupyter api